# Using a BNC shorting cap as a switch

Tags: bnc

Regarding [this short-circuit BNC cap](https://www.radiall.com/bnc-male-short-circuit-cap-with-chain-r141862000.html):

Is there a way to know if the cap is isolated from the inner BNC pins where the current will pass through?

I want to use this as a lock with a panel mounted BNC, so that when the cap is plugged it will act like a switch for 12 V. I am not sure whether the cap will also be at 12 V potential or not when it is plugged in.

I need a connector, rather than a switch, so it can also be extended by a cable to be used as an external lock.

[image]

Comment: Is the enclosure metallic? Is it connected to some potential like 0V ground of your circuit? The BNC metal chassis usually connects to enclosure metal chassis. Or does the BNC have a plastic insulation from metallic enclosure?

Comment: There is only one pin in a BNC plug. The other connection is the whole outside of the plug.

Comment: @Justme My case the BNC connector is isolated from the chassis see this: https://www.pasternack.com/images/Product/large/PE4091.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is there a way to know if the cap is isolated from the inner BNC pins
> where the current will pass through?*

The words "short circuit" are the giveaway: -

[image]

And, the fact that is talking about it being a male gender is also significant.

> *Im not sure whether the cap will also be in 12V potential or not when
> it is plugged in.*

The cap is grounded and will short the 12 volts on the panel connector to ground. If you need a non-shorting type, they are available from [here](https://www.pasternack.com/50-ohm-bnc-male-non-shorting-cap-pe6014-p.aspx) for example: -

[image]

From comments it appears that the outer part of the BNC is not grounded but, an alternative wiring of the inside of the enclosure can achieve this: -

[image]

Comment: I need to make an inter-lock but the metal enclosure has only bnc hole. It is for activating a 12V 520mW(275 ohm)  dpdt relay's magnet. My problem is I can only use this hole and I can only find BNC can fit there so I wanted to make BNC inter-lock. But then I needed to find a BNC shorting cap and I found this. But now from your answer I can see that the cap will expose the 12V to who touches it. Im a bit puzzle and couldnt find a better practical solution. Any input appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I mean I want bnc sig and gnd to be shorted when the cap is plugged. But I need the cap itself to be isolated from the pins.

Comment: The outer body of the panel mounted BNC connector is connected to what potential @ty_1917 <-- that will be the exposed voltage to the user. And, that is also exposed to the user even if the cap isn't in place so, I'm unsure what problem you envisage.

Comment: Do you mind if I make a drawing and get back in a few minutes.

Comment: @ty_1917 if the exposed part of the panel connector is OK for a user to touch then it will be no different when the cap is in place.

Comment: I see, but the cap would be plugged normally only will be unplugged if to be used as an inter-lock. But I see your point. Maybe I need a connector which doesnt expose the voltage. At the moment this is the connector https://www.pasternack.com/images/Product/large/PE9172_1.jpg I was looking a shorting cap for. The reason is the hole of the enclosure is for BNC panel mount connector.

Comment: I also made a quick hand sketch here https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQnCH.jpg showing the connector and the desired shorting cap. The dashed lines is enclosure.

Comment: @ty_1917 can you not re-wire like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DVPh.jpg <-- this puts GND on the outer of the BNC.

Comment: Definitely. Makes very sense!

Comment: Just last question though. Other answer says this might have 50 Ohm do you think it is? Otherwise I can make my own shorting BNC cap, since by wiring you suggested the potential exposed will be at ground level.

Comment: @ty_1917 when it mentions 50 ohm it means it is mechanically compatible BNCs that are used to connect with 50 ohm cable.

Answer (score 1):

The cap is a "short-circuit" type so it can be expected to have a direct electrical connection between the pin and the bayonet.

> I want to use this as a lock with a panel mounted BNC.

That's fine.

> So when the cap is plugged it will act like a switch for 12V.

What 12 V?

> But Im not sure whether the cap will also be in 12V potential or not when it is plugged in.

Show us a schematic diagram and where 12 V is in relation to the BNC. Note that these connectors are for signals and not power.

---

Reviewing your sketch:

There is only one pin in a BNC plug. The other connection is the whole outside of the plug. As you have sketched it the whole plug will be at 12 V and if mounted on a metal panel then so will the panel. You risk a short-circuit with this arrangement.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbrzTh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Alternate arrangement.*

Configuring as shown in Figure 1 has the following advantages:

- The shell of the socket and the plug (when inserted) will be at ground potential.
- The 12 V supply current is limited by the relay coil's resistance in any connection to the plug pin.
- If mounted on a metal chassis or panel, the panel will be at ground potential.

It's not the right socket for the job but I presume you are doing this as a "secret" switch.

Comment: The datasheet from the link in the question does contain ``Impedance 50 Ω``, which is a bit confusing since the description is ``MALE SHORT CIRCUIT CAP``.

Comment: Agreed. I took it to mean for 50 ohm cable / terminals. "Short circuit" seems fairly definative though.

Comment: Here to be more clear I copy paste my comment to Andy's answer "I need to make an inter-lock but the metal enclosure has only bnc hole. It is for activating a 12V 520mW(275 ohm)  dpdt relay's magnet. My problem is I can only use this hole and I can only find BNC can fit there so I wanted to make BNC inter-lock. But then I needed to find a BNC shorting cap and I found this. But now from your answer I can see that the cap will expose the 12V to who touches it. Im a bit puzzle and couldnt find a better practical solution. Any input appreciated.2

Comment: I also made a quick hand sketch here https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQnCH.jpg showing the connector and the desired shorting cap. The dashed lines is enclosure.

Comment: @ty_1917, See the update.

Answer (score 1):

Move the relay to between the 12V supply and the center pin, and ground the shield.

You then have 12V, current limited by the relay (275Ω at 12V will let through ~45mA), on the center pin.  When the cap is in place the whole thing is at your ground potential.

Answer (score 0):

BNC comes in twinax and triax versions, both of which have two conductors that are isolated from the housing. Both types are significantly more expensive than standard BNC connectors, but twinax are generally cheaper than triax ones.  Photos from https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/BNC_connector
[image: BNC twinax]
[image: BNC triax]